# How to check checkbox property in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In the following snippet I want to check whether or not the radio checkbox have been checked:

```js
d3.selectAll("input[name='test1']").on("click", function() {
  // log 'this'
  console.log("this will always be true", d3.select(this).property("checked"))
  // log selected property yields different result on 'no'
  var selectTest = d3.selectAll("input[name='test1']").property("checked")
  console.log("This will be false on 'no': ", selectTest)
})
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset ="utf-8">
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<input value="Yes" type="radio" name="test1">Yes
<input value="No" type="radio" name="test1">No

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the first method

```
console.log("this will always be true", d3.select(this).property("checked"))
```

Works as intended, but the other method gives you a `false` value when you select "No" for some reason I can't figure out, and I can't find any other examples of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation is simple: your selection has **two** elements. However, the getter will get only the **first one**.

You can see this if you use an `each`:

```js
d3.selectAll("input[name='test1']").on("click", function() {
  d3.selectAll("input[name='test1']").each(function(_, i) {
    console.log("radio " + (i + 1) + " is: " + d3.select(this).property("checked"))
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<input value="Yes" type="radio" name="test1">Yes
<input value="No" type="radio" name="test1">No
```

Another way to show this even clearer is the following demo: I'm selecting **all** circles and using a getter to get the `fill` value. Despite the fact that there are two circles, blue and red, I'm getting only "blue" as result (the first one):

```js
console.log(d3.selectAll("circle").attr("fill"))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <circle cx="100" cy="75" r="10" fill="blue"></circle>
  <circle cx="200" cy="75" r="10" fill="red"></circle>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an id to differentiate the two:

```
<input value="Yes" type="radio" name="test1" id="test1">Yes
<input value="No" type="radio" name="test1" id="test2">No
```

then..

```
d3.select("input[id='test1']").on("click", function() {..})
```

Comment: I know how to do that, that's not what I need in this particular scenario, thanks for the suggestion though